# How to fix powerline fonts and symbols error in shell?

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've installed Arch about a week ago, and since then I been struggling with the powerline fonts. But after installing the pkg `powerline-fonts`, I configured the `.zshrc` file by adding these lines:

```
 powerline-daemon -q 
. /usr/share/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh
```

The best I could do is commenting the line in the `.zshrc`file that chooses a specific theme and letting the above code to run, and looks like this: [powerline-fonts fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKHqR.png).

Still, the `oh-my-zsh` themes don't work; for example this is the agnoster theme: [agnoster theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqsml.png).

Another issue I have is that the symbols or the numbers are not shown properly in the terminal, any terminal, for example when using `broot`:[br listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lBSN.png)
or `bat`: [bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htTeI.jpg)

I think these problems are linked and that's why I've asked the two questions in one.
My question is: How could I fix this and have the `oh-my-zsh` themes work properly?
On my vm they look like this:[agnoster-theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJK19.jpg) and [bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLcPb.jpg).
I would like to make them look identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Good Ol' Locale

One issue I have had come up is not having my locale set, which causes all sorts of headache and misery to befall the unaware. To set it, go to `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment the US English locale: `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` then as root run `locale-gen` and as root again  `localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8` just to be extra sure. Then reboot and if the issue persists check out this guide from [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale) and see if the steps there work for you.

---

### Alternative Installation Method

Additionally and to rule out another possible problem, you can try an alternative method of installing powerline, first you will need to download python-pip, then you will use it to download powerline.

```
sudo pacman -S git python
su -c 'pip install git+git://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline'
```

Now this new installation of powerline is in `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/powerline/` so add the following to `.zshrc`

```
if [[ -r /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh ]]; then
  source /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh
fi
```

and you may want to alternatively install the powerline fonts, to do so try the below:

```
 wget https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/10-powerline-symbols.conf
 sudo mv PowerlineSymbols.otf /usr/share/fonts/
 sudo fc-cache -vf
 sudo mv 10-powerline-symbols.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
```

---

This is not an exhaustive list, there is simply a lot of different avenues to pursue with rectifying this one which I haven't had come up in a long time (I scripted out my installation from ISO then another one provisions my dotfiles and installs my programs to taste, which spares me these headaches generally but causes a bunch of its own) but I do hope it helps or leads you along the right path!

Comment: I was using Fedora, and I had my locale set to "en-CA" which is actually not supported... I had it working by looking at your answer, and used "en-US". Problem solved.